# append data to an array rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to append data to a variable

```
@celebrity = Celebrity.includes(:category).where('category_id = ?', params[:id])
test =[]
@celebrity.each do |celeb|
  @vote = Vote.where('celebrity_id = ?', celeb).count
  test  << {vote_count:@vote}
end
```

when i debug 'test',

```
abort test.inspect
```

I am getting the result of

```
[{:vote_count=>2}, {:vote_count=>1}, {:vote_count=>0}]
```

but, my question is how can I append vote_count to @celebrity , can anyone please help me out

Comment: Please share your expected result.

Comment: '<Celebrity id: 7, name: "Di Caprio", gender: false, category_id: "1", , image_file_name: "422817.jpg", image_content_type: "image/jpeg", image_file_size: 132673, image_updated_at: "2015-07-20 08:20:53",vote_count=>2>]' 
This is what i am expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@celebrity.each do |celeb|
  celeb["vote_count"] = celeb.votes.count
end
```

+apneadiving is right. use counter_caches

Comment: wow... just do this and youre fine http://yerb.net/blog/2014/03/13/three-easy-steps-to-using-counter-caches-in-rails/

Comment: after adding "votes_count" attribute to my table its fixed, but in voting action I can't able to vote for a celebrity, getting this error 'missing attribute: votes_count'.My code:
    'celebrity = Celebrity.find(params[:id])
    vote = Vote.build(celebrity_id: celebrity.id, :id => params[:vote])   
  respond_to do |format|     
     if vote.save
      format.html { redirect_to ranking_url }
      format.json { render json: vote, status: :created }
     else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json:  vote.errors,status::unprocessable_entity}
  end
  end'

Comment: Pastebin Or pastie.org

Answer (score 2):

You should not do it this way, its terrible in terms of performance.

If you setup a `counter_cache` properly ([see ref](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache)), you'd have data right away in your model instances as expected